# magento output custom options

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Is it possible to output the available list of custom options onto the view.phtml page within Magento? Obviously the drop down lists allow you to filter down but I need to list them in a html table and allow the customer to add to cart on each item.

Comment: you want to show all types of custom options in table format ?

Comment: I managed to sort this by using configurable products instead of custom options. I could then extract them into a table format.

Comment: Please add comments to my answer.You have an `add comment` option just below my answer. Put comment over here is intended for every one who views this question. Some time I may not notified.

Comment: Please read you question once again.. You are not giving any clue to show whether you need this for configurable product. Please `edit` your question accordingly. Edit option is available just below your question in left side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you how to convert `dropdown` and `multi-select` options into table format. This is the code that do the trick.

```
<?php
$product = Mage::Registry('current_product');
$options = $product->getOptions();
//check for option exists
if($options):
    foreach ($options as $option) :
        //table format allows only for select options
        if($option->getType()== Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN || 
            $option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE):

            $require = ($option->getIsRequire()) ? ' required-entry' : '';
            if($option->getType()== Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN):
                    $value_name = 'options['.$option->getid().']';
            else:
                $value_name = 'options['.$option->getid().'][]';
            endif;
?>
            <table border="1" style="width:500px;margin-bottom:30px">
                <thead>
                    <tr<?php if ($option->getIsRequire()) echo ' class="required"' ?>>
                        <th><?php echo $option->getTitle() ?></th>
                        <th><?php if ($option->getIsRequire()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="<?php echo 'select_'.$option->getId() ?>" class="<?php echo $require.' product-custom-option' ?>">       
            <?php
                foreach ($option->getValues() as  $values) :
                    $value = $values->getOptionTypeId();
                    $value_title = $values->getTitle();
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                                if($option->getType()== Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN):
                            ?>
                                    <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $value_name; ?>" class="radio_option" id="<?php echo 'radio_option_'.$value ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
                            <?php
                                else:
                            ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $value_name; ?>" class="checkbox_option" id="<?php echo 'checkbox_option_'.$value ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
                            <?php
                                endif;
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $value_title; ?></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php
                endforeach;
            ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
<?php
        endif;  
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Here for `dropdown` options, we are using `radio button` to show their values. For `multiselect` options, `checkbox` inputs are used. So if checkbox appears in the table, that means it a  multi select option and hence more than one checkboxes can have tick at a time. Since radio buttons are used for dropdown options, it is important to make sure that, only one radio button is checked at a time. (We need to use javascript for ensure this).

So if we are set some custom options for a product through admin like this..

[image: Admin Custom Options]

The output correspond to our code will be look like this

[image]

**Note:** Please note that, the code is in very basic format. You may require additional css and javascripts make it more user frontly.  This is for giving you a basic idea and additional css, js are hence out of box topic.

For more information about code, check out [**my blog**](http://rajeev-k-tomy.blogspot.in/2014/07/get-values-of-custom-option.html)

Hope it helps